# Issue converting current project to Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, eclipse-kepler

I am **Converting my current project into Maven project**. after clicking on "Convert to Maven" i got below Error

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'ActiTime'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

I have added **POI,POI-ooxml,Selenium , testNg Dependencies** but now i am getting

```
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.48.2: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:pom:2.48.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/2.48.2/selenium-java-2.48.2.pom
```

Can anyone look into this
I am using Eclipse Keepler as ID and JDK 1.7

Below is Screenshot  POM.XML and error. please refer this
[image]

Comment: Do you have internet connection? Why are you modifying settings.xml ? You can add repository location in your pom.xml too

Comment: indeed, the basic error is "Could not transfer artifact org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:pom:2.48.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out" - that's a basic internet connectivity error. Maven will want to download all kinds of files from the online Maven repositories at least the first time you do a build.

Comment: @BilboBaggins yes i have internet connection. actually i searched for this issue on internet and there is no "settings.xml" file .m2 folder... so i added this above file manually

Comment: @Gimby so is this expected error. If it is then how to resolve this one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308079/why-maven-settings-xml-file-is-not-there Refer to this :) settings.xml is not required by default, it is required when you want to override the repository setting so remove it and try again

Comment: You have Internet connection. But Maven does not. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @BilboBaggins ohkk.. thanks
I have removed "settings.xm"l file but still issue exist. please refer screenshot i have attatched

Comment: @Tunaki :  yeah i have net connection.. May be maven don't have...Actually i don't have any idea about configuration of maven...i known theoretically which i googled .. i am implementing Automation in my project this is the last step which is remaining
so if the issue with Maven Connectivity then how to connect Maven with Net

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @Tunaki :  no tunaki

Comment: If you just paste http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 in a browser, does that work (you see a long listing of links) ?

Comment: Are you building the project using the option of Build Project in eclipse? Try ALT+ SHIFT+ X  AND M combo it will ask you for a option(goals) specify clean install and run it that way and let me know what happens, further more the dependency error is for maven-resource-plugin which I can not see in your pom. Refresh(F5) the project and change workspace settings. (go to Preference -> WorkSpace -> use native hooks )

Comment: @BilboBaggins i pressed alt+shift+X and clicked on "Run Maven Build" then a new popup opened
under goals i clicked on "Select Button" and a new window opened
in that "GOAL" window thereis no data/records and belowit's coming(No Entries available with error sign symbol)
I checked or unchecked the "USe Qualified Name" checkbox but didn't any Enteries in GOAL Window

Comment: @Gimby i typed repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 in firefox window and page opened with Heading "Index of /maven2/" having lot of records like directory

Comment: @RahilKumar You won't find it you have to write it manually. Also try the ALT + F5  i.e. ( right click on project -> Maven -> Update Project Configuration)

Comment: @BilboBaggins i did as you said btu still project is successfully failing  :). Below is console output
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project ActiTime: Execution default-clean of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-

Comment: Try install only, right click -> maven -> Maven install

Comment: @BilboBaggins  Failed to execute goal on project ActiTime: Could not resolve dependencies for project ActiTime:ActiTime:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:2.48.2, nodep:jar:2.1_3, , commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4, org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3, net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.18, xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2, org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4, 
And many more jars are missing .shared Google drive location :)

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxB7qXe0EYGpTThUQlJUTEFYNTA

Comment: I can't see it, share your project on github and provide me the link on it I will try to resolve it for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93458/discussion-between-bilbo-baggins-and-rahil-kumar).

Comment: @BilboBaggins thanks gentleman for help