# Unable to bulid sucessfully in Netbeans showing error

Tags: windows, netbeans

---

### BUILD FAILURE

### Total time:  12.968 s
Finished at: 2023-03-01T16:54:08+05:30

Failed to execute goal on project unicentaopos: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.unicenta:unicentaopos:jar:5.0-BETA: Failed to collect dependencies at org.jpos:jpos:jar:2.0.10 -> com.sleepycat:je:jar:7.0.6: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.sleepycat:je:jar:7.0.6: Could not transfer artifact com.sleepycat:je:pom:7.0.6 from/to spring-repo (https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/): authentication failed for https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.pom, status: 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

I study detail mention in above link.But not reach appropriate point . And also confuse where ia my .m2/settings.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the settings.xml on your own: [Why maven settings.xml file is not there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308079/why-maven-settings-xml-file-is-not-there)

Regarding your error: you should you Maven central instead of repo.spring.io. For an explanantion see [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020).